# Heroku gettext installation

Tags: django, heroku, gettext

I want to install gettext in Heroku. I have added: `https://github.com/lexifdev/heroku-buildpack-gettext.git` into the buildpacks section of my app. However, when I run

`heroku run python manage.py compilemessages -l en`

I get the error message: `CommandError: Can't find msgfmt. Make sure you have GNU gettext tools 0.15 or newer installed.`

Comment: You use Heroku for deployment, don't you? Normally messages are compiled at development time, and the resulting compiled message files are stored in the repository (suboptimal in theory but it's the common practice).

Comment: So I just push the .po and .mo files to Heroku and then django will handle the rest?

Comment: I think so. I'm not certain. Try it.

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problem my friend. Here's how I fixed it:

From the heroku dashboard, add the following buildpack: https://github.com/grauwoelfchen/heroku-buildpack-gettext.git

On your next deployment to heroku (e.g. a git push), it and any other buildpacks you have will be built and installed and all should work.

Comment: Make sure you have something in your commit to trigger the change, I did a small `README` change and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I did it
type the following commands

heroku buildpacks: add https://github.com/grauwoelfchen/heroku-buildpack-gettext

git push heroku master

Now, the gettext will be added

Comment: thanks for the great suggestion. You included a space between `buildpacks:`and `add`, which should not be there, though. The command should be: `heroku buildpacks:add https://github.com/grauwoelfchen/heroku-buildpack-gettext`